# what does a blue RJ jack insert mean?

Tags: networking

Good day, I have searched for the meaning of casing colors for RJ jack inserts, but haven't found one.

Please indicate: what does a blue RJ jack insert mean?

Comment: It depends on device) Cisco uses blue RJ for console cables some times. What devicedo you have?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Could you post a picture?

Comment: Regular office setting with faceplate which has two jacks.. one blue, another red. One is for phone, the other for data. Which one is for phone? or data?

Comment: Blue jacks are for male computers, pink jacks for female computers.  That's how you tell the gender of a computer.  If it has both, the computer is bi-sexual.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean colour coded like

[image]

If so, I don't think there is any official standard here, people choose colours and then decide how they are going to use them

Comment: it's right, the color of RJ jack is only to do a smart labeling process, isnt logic to have an especific departament like a rainbow, and ad @user996142 said, some brands use them for an especific use as internal definitions like black/blue ones for console.